# Timezones management - server/client - struggling to understand

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datetime, timezone

I've been reading a whole day today. I want to understand how to manage time in my webapp. So just a few bits of information to begin with: I have Laravel 9 backend and Vue3 frontend - a monolith app.

On the front end, users can create an entry in the database which contains the start and end date.

Now the problematic thing - so I want to make it so that when a user in one country creates the entry, that user will see their local time but if the user in another timezone sees that entry on the website they will see that shifted accordingly to their timezone.

Now if on the front end I am using `new Date ()` in JS to obtain the date like this `Tue Dec 27 2022 19:40:08 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)` and then send it over to laravel I get something like that in database `2022-12-27 19:40:08`.

Here is what I know:

- UTC is not a timezone but a time system
- `new Date()` called in my JS app in the browser is giving me the local, time-zoned time
- Laravel by default uses UTC

Both dates on the frontend and database in Laravel are the same. How that is if once of them is local time and the other one is UTC?

Can anyone explain exactly how does that work from database/js/laravel point of view? Or at least point me to some good resources?

The way I see that is I need to:

- create UTC date in JS on the frontend
- send it to the LAravel app which will save it in UTC in my db
- display it for the user after formatting it on the frontend with Javascript to use local timezone.

It all seems very confusing to me and so far I just managed to get mostly mean comments for not understanding this.

I am mostly interested in understanding what is the correct flow here and how when I send a date from Javascript to the backend, Laravel knows how to deal with it.

Can anyone explain that?

Comment: For testing, you could have a second client device set to a different time zone and see if the display dates change properly.  The combination you are using might be converting to and from UTC transparently.

Comment: You can pass the time in what ever time zone you want to the backend, as long as it contains information about which time zone it's using, or the diff it is from GMT/UTC. If no such information is passed, then it should assume it's UTC. The backend can then convert it to UTC, which is what you're storing, using in queries etc. The backend then always returns the dates in UTC and lets the client handle the conversion to it's local time zone.

Comment: It's not that complicated. You always work in UTC unless you show a date to the user or you receive input from the user. Given the timezone the user is in you convert from local to UTC time or visa-versa.

Comment: @M.Eriksson that is what I was looking for I think - simple confirmation of what to pass and what is supposed to happen. I think I will give it a shot and run some tests now.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yeah it seems it is fairly easy just need to know I got it right.

Comment: When you create today's date in the browser you can use `new Date().toISOString()`, which returns a UTC date string like `'2022-12-27T23:06:34.789Z'`, e.g. it is converted to UTC, and is not local time. Store that in the database. When you get a UTC date from the server you can convert that to a date object, such as `new Date('2022-12-27T23:06:34.789Z')`, which you can format to a local date format of choice. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: If you're just interested in the *current* date and time when you create an entry in the database, there's no reason to have the browser send it to you at all. Take the UTC date and time directly from the server.  You have more control that way, as you can be assured your server's clock is synchronized.

Comment: Be aware that UTC timestamps an hour or less before the end of DST will have 2 valid conversions, one in DST, the other not.  Leap seconds have a similar issue.  Also, you should ensure each client has the same TZ DB.